# Assign all the Order to related Customers on database

Tags: database, orders, email

My website got hacked and all the customers were deleted, but the orders are still here.

I imported back the customers by CSV, but the orders are no longer assigned/linked to them. The only commun point is the email address in the orders details and the email address in customers accounts.

I need to know how I can assign again orders to customers in the database. Is it possible to find a way to link them again using the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.
In case of multiple deletion, use those 2 sql queries. First sql query will link orders to customers, and second query will show the orders in the customers account (orders tab)

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order as SFO  
INNER JOIN customer_entity as C  
ON C.email = SFO.customer_email  
SET SFO.customer_id = C.entity_id  
WHERE SFO.customer_is_guest = 0 

UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid as SFOG  
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order as SFO  
ON SFO.entity_id = SFOG.entity_id  
SET SFOG.customer_id = SFO.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this query worked, and I can see the client in the order and click on his name to go see his info.

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order as SFO INNER JOIN customer_entity as C on C.email = SFO.customer_email SET SFO.customer_id = C.entity_id WHERE SFO.customer_is_guest = 0
```

But when I go to the client's info, Orders Tab, there are no orders.

Answer (score 0):

it's return the  Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'FOR sales_flat_order_grid Table' at line 6**strong text**